# How to merge two tables in phpMyAdmin such that there won't be duplicate entry?

Tags: mysql, merge

This is bit complicated for me to explain, I am trying my best. I have one database with name quotes. In this database I have four tables, two of them are imported from other database. Now I want to merge these tables into 2 tables. tables are author and author_new and quotes and quotes_new. I want to merge authors_new to authors and quotes_new to quotes but the problem is that there are some relation between them like there is an Id of each author and this Id is given in quotes with coloumn auth_id.

The author with Id 1 has 10 or more quotes and each quote have auth_id 1
now if we merge the id of authors from author_new will change so the auth_id in quote will also change and the relation of author with quotes will not be maintain. so please suggest me some answer where i can merge the data also and the relation will also maintain.   hope you understood my problem.

here are example tables for understanding the scenario

```
        author

       id      | author_name    | 
       -------------------------------------
       1          Jack
       2          John     
       3          Jill   
       4          Mack

       author_new

    id      | author_name    | 
    ------------------------------------>merge this in author
     1           Harry
     2           Micky     
     3           Jack  



      quotes

      id      |quotes      | auth_id
      -------------------------
       1         i love...     2
       2         i am .....    1
       3         i was....     2
       4         we are....    3


       quotes_new

       id      |quotes      | auth_id
       --------------------------------->merge this in quotes
       1         we  wil...     2
       2         i  am .....    1
       3         we know...     2





       Result After merging


    author

   id      | author_name    | 
   ---------------------------------
    1          Jack
    2          John     
    3          Jill   
    4          Mack
    5          harry
    6          Micky


     quotes

    id      |quotes      | auth_id
     -------------------------
     1         i love...     2
     2         i am .....    1
     3         i was....     2
     4         we are....    3
     5         we  wil...    5
     6         i  am .....   6
```

Comment: I think you have to do it manually if you want to keep relationship as it is

Comment: Can you show us the 4 tables (no need of real data) so we can do it on mysql fiddle ?

Comment: brother its not one two entries its 20 lakh quotes and 20 thousands authors..how it is possible

Comment: ya sure i am just creating tables...

Comment: Should 'Jack' with id 3 in `author_new` be merged with the 'Jack' with id 1 in `author` or can those be considered different?

Comment: yes buddy relation of jack with his quote in quotes is already set with auth_id 1 in quotes...so we cant change this relation of author name with their quotes....jack is already there is author so no need to insert it again jack in author_new should skip....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we ignore the fact that 'authors' may be in both the `author` and `author_new` table, the migration of the data is pretty straight forward, it just involves a couple of steps to take:

First, create intermediate tables which will contain all the data for the original and new tables, this enables you to have new id's.

```
CREATE TABLE author_origin (
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  originTable VARCHAR(16),
  originId INT(11),
  name VARCHAR(32),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE quotes_origin (
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  originTable VARCHAR(16),
  originId INT(11) UNSIGNED,
  authorId INT(11) UNSIGNED,
  quote VARCHAR(128),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Next, copy the data from both `author` and `author_new` into `author_origin` and the same for the quote tables.

```
INSERT INTO author_origin (originTable, originId, name)
SELECT 'author', id, name
  FROM author;
INSERT INTO author_origin (originTable, originId, name)
SELECT 'author_new', id, name
  FROM author_new;

INSERT INTO quotes_origin (originTable, originId, authorId, quote)
SELECT 'quotes', id, authorId, quote
  FROM quotes;
INSERT INTO quotes_origin (originTable, originId, authorId, quote)
SELECT 'quotes_new', id, authorId, quote
  FROM quotes_new;
```

Then, you'll want to create the final structure you'll be using (I just used the same simple structure I extracted from your examples)

```
CREATE TABLE author_final (
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(32),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE quotes_final (
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  authorId INT(11) UNSIGNED,
  quote VARCHAR(128),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Now, all that is left is to copy the data into the 'final' tables.
Authors are pretty straight forward (only skipping the 'origin' fields)

```
INSERT INTO author_final
SELECT id, name
  FROM author_origin;
```

The quotes are slightly more cumbersome, as you will need to reference the newly generated authorId's

```
INSERT INTO quotes_final
(SELECT q.id, a.id, q.quote
  FROM quotes_origin q
 INNER JOIN author_origin a 
    ON a.originTable = 'author' AND a.originId=q.authorId
 WHERE q.originTable = 'quotes')
 UNION
 (SELECT q.id, a.id, q.quote
  FROM quotes_origin q
 INNER JOIN author_origin a 
    ON a.originTable = 'author_new' AND a.originId=q.authorId
 WHERE q.originTable = 'quotes_new');
```

I've created a [working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2456f7/1) which does this these steps

---

As you answered my comment pretty much while I was rounding up my example steps, I'll simply describe the process to actually merge the `author` and `author_new` solely based on the username.

The primary change would be to have the `name` field in the intermediate `author_origin` to be unique and to have separate fields for the originating tables, something like

```
CREATE TABLE author_origin (
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(32),
  authorId INT(11) UNSIGNED,
  authorNewId INT(11) UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  UNIQUE KEY (name)
);
```

And then you'll want to update the appropriate fields depending on the originating table, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO author_origin (name, authorNewId)
SELECT name, id
  FROM author_new
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE authorNewId=id;
```

From then on it is just a matter of changing the conditions within the final `UNION` query to use the appropriate `authorId` or `authorNewId`

Reluctant to create a new fiddle as I don't appreciate the all-caps comments, still [here's a working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69f20/1), which does exactly as you so eloquently requested (you should do the right thing and update the question to reflect this new requirement).

Comment: BUDDY WHAT IF AUTHOR WITH SAME NAME ARE PRESENT IN BOTH AUTHOR AND AUTHOR_NEW

Comment: I suggest you read through to the end (and hit caps lock once)

Comment: can you please make changes in mysql fiddle and get the exact result....and yes the final query insert into quotes_final is not showing accurate result only quotes from quotes_new are inserted and other quotes are not being inserted

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean, I've [updated the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42a3c/2) to prove quotes are both originating from `quotes` and `quotes_new` (in the fiddle quotes for `quotes_new` now have `' new'` appended to them). For the rest, you wanted to know how to merge the tables and I feel like I've answered that for you. Creating the statements to migrate your data is now up to you. I believe I've more than answered your question (including the updated requirement), now it is your turn to learn from it and solve _your_ problem.